# PostgreSQL referencing error

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a landlord table and a listing table.  when creating my listing table, I received this error.

```
ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "t_property_landlord"
SQL state: 42830

create table if not exists t_listing(
    rental_listing_id BIGSERIAL primary key,
    landlord_id BIGSERIAL references t_property_landlord(landlord_id),
    available varchar(25),
    rent numeric,
    deposit numeric,
    description text,
    term varchar(25),
    pet boolean,
    feature JSON,
    post_ts date,
    view numeric,
    create_ts timestamp default now()
);
```

Here is the landlord table.

```
create table if not exists t_property_landlord(
    landlord_id BIGSERIAL,
    email varchar(100) references t_user(email),
    property_id BIGSERIAL references t_property(property_id),
    change_ts timestamp default now(),
    active boolean default true,
    primary key(email,property_id)
);
```

I tried create create_ts, and reference the landlord_id, making those you unique but still not working.  Can someone take a look and let me know what I'm doing wrong?  I am using PostgreSQL 9.4

thanks,

Comment: `landlord_id BIGSERIAL references t_property_landlord(landlord_id), ` -->> `landlord_id BIGINT references t_property_landlord(landlord_id),` ( and the same for `property_id`)

Comment: bigserial auto-increments. you don't want to use that for your foreign keys. only the parent record that the foreign keys actually point at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

t_property_landlord.landlord_id isn't a unique column. It needs to be for a foreign key to be able to reference it.  See here for information about how to declare one: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/ddl-constraints.html

Your t_property_landlord table should look like this:

```
create table if not exists t_property_landlord(
    landlord_id BIGSERIAL UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    email varchar(100) references t_user(email),
    property_id BIGSERIAL references t_property(property_id),
    change_ts timestamp default now(),
    active boolean default true,
    primary key(email,property_id)
);
```

In the end, you might want to take another look at your design, as you are trying to make a foreign key reference a column in another table that is not that table's primary key. Usually, foreign keys should reference primary keys.

Comment: oh wow, I thought BIGSERIAL is similar to auto number auto number and is unique.  thank you so much